# How to view the Safari version in Setting of iPhone iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

I can not find the Safari version in Setting of iPhone. 
Could any genius give some clue? 
How to view the Safari version in Setting of iPhone iOS?
[image]

I viewed the website that it said the Safari version is binding with iOS version.
Such as iOS version is 13.*.*, then the Safari version is 13. 
Is it right? 
https://www.lifewire.com/check-the-version-number-of-safari-446563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can visit https://spiderip.com/ to check the user agent and version of safari. 
   But I don't know whether this side is safe.
   [image]

I guess the function which will get the userAgent is in the below.

```
  var k=this;  {var ia=k.navigator;if(ia){var ja=ia.userAgent;if(ja){w=ja;break a}}w=""}
```

2. The other solution is that you can write a html page with the javascript in the below.

```
    javascript:alert(this.navigator.userAgent)
```